# Gradient of a nonlinear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

I would like to take the gradient of the following function with respect to $x_{ki}$

$$D = (\frac{13}{12})^N - \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^N(1 + \frac{1}{2}|x_{ki}-0.5| - \frac{1}{2}|x_{ki}-0.5|^2) \\
+ \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^N[1+\frac{1}{2}|x_{ki}-0.5| + \frac{1}{2}|x_{li}-0.5|-\frac{1}{2}|x_{ki}-x_{li}|] $$

Now I know that when $f(x) = |u(x)| = \sqrt{(u^2(x))}$ then $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{u(x)}{\sqrt{(u^2(x))}}$

So, if we let $N=2$ then I can begin computing $\frac{\partial D}{\partial x_{k1}}$ by looking at the first term:

**Attempted solution**

1st term partial derivative:
$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial x_{k1}} = \frac{2}{n}(1 + \frac{1}{2}|x_{k2}-0.5| - \frac{1}{2}|x_{k2}-0.5|^2)*(\frac{1}{2}\frac{x_{k1}-0.5}{\sqrt{(x_{k1}-0.5)^2}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2(x_{k1}-0.5)}{\sqrt{(x_{k1}-0.5)^2}}) \\
= \frac{2}{n}(1 + \frac{1}{2}|x_{k2}-0.5| - \frac{1}{2}|x_{k2}-0.5|^2)*(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x_{k1}-0.5}{\sqrt{(x_{k1}-0.5)^2}})$$

2nd term partial derivative:
$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial x_{k1}} = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{l=1}[1+\frac{1}{2}|x_{k2}-0.5| + \frac{1}{2}|x_{l2}-0.5|-\frac{1}{2}|x_{k2}-x_{l2}|]*(\frac{1}{2}\frac{x_{k1}-0.5}{\sqrt{(x_{k1}-0.5)^2}} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{x_{k1}-x_{l1}}{\sqrt{(x_{k1}-x_{l1})^2}})$$

and you would combine the terms for the full derivative

**Questions**:

1. is this the correct approach?
2. for $\frac{\partial D}{\partial x_{k2}}$ would you simply switch the $x_{k1}$ and $x_{k2}$ terms?

3. What if N was an arbitrary dimension? Would the product contain identical constants of the different indices (ie: $\prod_{i=1\not\in LHS}^N\frac{2}{n}(1 + \frac{1}{2}|x_{ki}-0.5| - \frac{1}{2}|x_{ki}-0.5|^2)$ multiplied by the derivative term?
4. Can this easily be extended for the Hessian? My goal is to utilize the gradient and hessian matrices in an optimization routine

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is the objective function of your optimization problem, I would recommend you reformulate your problem into a smooth problem: replace any $|y_i|$ with $p_i + n_i$, subject to the constraints $y_i = p_i - n_i$ and $p_i, n_i \ge 0$.